# Excel 2013 crashes when unhiding columns

Tags: vba, excel

I've spent hours trying to figure this out with no solution being found so far.  I have a macro (see below) that unhides/hides a range on a spreadsheet.  Seems simple enough and the first two times I run this macro it works fine; however, the third time, which is always unhiding the range, usually causes Excel 2013 to crash.  I read [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=91152) that having an volatile user defined function in the range I'm unhiding might be causing the problem, but I already tried making the function not volatile and Excel still crashed.  Does anyone have any ideas or experienced this before?

```
Sub HideShowSQLCreator(control As IRibbonControl)

Dim SQL_Creator As Range
Dim Report_Home_Cell As Range

Set SQL_Creator = Sheets("Report").Range("SQL_Creator")
Set Report_Home_Cell = Sheets("Report").Range("Report_Home_Cell")

If SQL_Creator.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
    SQL_Creator.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Report_Home_Cell.EntireRow.Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    ActiveSheet.Range("Report_Home_Cell").Select
    Exit Sub
End If

If SQL_Creator.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
    SQL_Creator.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    SQL_Creator.Select
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any controls (form controls or activeX controls) on the sheet? I once had a similar problem and it occurred when un-hiding (Excel automatically moving the controls) and thereby shifting the controls out of boundary of the sheet.

Comment: Nope, don't have any of those.

Comment: You mentioned you had a user defined function in the column you are trying to hide/unhide.  Have you tried commenting out that function or deleting the formulas the utilize the function and running your code?  This will just help you narrow down which macro is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it still crashed - but I did figure it out eventually.  See below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I got frustrated and figured the workbook was just corrupted so I created a new one from scratch.  The macro was working fine until I got to the end and realized that the crash had to do with a big pivot table to the right of the range I was trying to hide/unhide.  I'm not sure why it happened, but my solution was to just put the columns I was trying to hide/unhide in a separate sheet in the workbook.  The macro works fine with them in separate sheets.  Weird stuff, but I'm glad there was a solution in the end.